# Efficient Method to Search in an Array where the maximum difference between previous and current element is 1

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Array has property that an element in array can be equal , less than 1 or greater than 1 the previous element .
e.g.  6,6,6,5,4,3,3,4,5,5.

Better than O(N) solution needed as it is asked in the interview.

Comment: If you look at an index `i` and it has a value 5 higher than what you're searching for, you can skip straight to `i+5`, yes? Strictly speaking, I guess that's still O(n), but...

Comment: hmm.. i+5 and i-5 both i think .

Comment: You could look at Interpolation Search or Jump search, they might offer some insight

Comment: Jump search only works for ordered lists. Without any order, you cannot make any decision(read optimizations) given a index. It will need a preprocessing step which is O(n)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there exists a solution better than `O(N)`. Here is a worst case: if you are searching for 5 in an array which contains only 6's you have to check every single entries.

Comment: agreed with you. but is there some fast method on average case ?

Comment: Average case ? On which set ? With which probability ?

Comment: got it. using jump search also we may have to traverse all the element of array. tnx